# Не запускаются методы

Tags: c#, unity3d, методы, unity3d-editor

У меня есть такой код

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LayersGlobal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LayersGlobal Instance;
    public string[] layers;
    public Dictionary<string, int> layersD = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("s");
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            InitializeLayersD();
        }
    
    }

    void InitializeLayersD()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < layers.Length; i++)
        {
            layersD[layers[i]] = 1 << i;
        }
    }

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    void Update()
    {
    
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            InitializeLayersD();
        }
        InitializeLayersD();
    }
}
```

И в етом коде почемуто не запускаются методы Awake и Update хотя вроде должны были запускатся
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тег `[ExecuteInEditMode]` надо ставить перед объявлением класса, а не конкретных функций. Пример из документации:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PrintAwake : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Editor causes this Awake");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Editor causes this Update");
    }
}
```